# Numba.cuda.copy_to_host is very slow on google colab

Tags: python, cuda, google-colaboratory, numba

Im trying to use numba.cuda for some matrix opration. I have two numpy arrays like this:
`A.shape`
(145, 8481)
`A[0][0]`
0.00011791062374719962
`B.shape`
(8481,)
`B[0]`
3.590439381300684
My code:

```
import math
import sys
import numpy as np
arr = np.load('arr.npy')
 

def tf_idf_calc(arr_word_coord):
    tf_list_np = np.zeros(arr_word_coord.shape)
    idf_list_np = np.zeros(arr_word_coord.shape[1])
    stop = 1  # чтоб idf посчитался только для первой строки, а не для всех
    for i in range(arr_word_coord.shape[0]):
        size = arr_word_coord.shape[1]
        for s in range(size):
            tf_list_np[i,s] = arr_word_coord[i][s]/size
            if stop == 1:
                count = 0
                for k in arr_word_coord[:,s]:
                    if k != 0:
                        count += 1
                    if count == 0:
                        count = 1
                idf_list_np[s] = math.log(arr_word_coord[:,s].size/count)
    return tf_list_np,idf_list_np 

A,B = tf_idf_calc(arr)
```

```
A_t = A.astype('float32')
B_t = B.astype('float32')
c = np.zeros(A_t.shape).astype(np.float32)

threadsperblock = (16,16)
blockspergrid_x = int(np.ceil(c.shape[0] / threadsperblock[0]))
blockspergrid_y = int(np.ceil(c.shape[1] / threadsperblock[1]))
blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y)  # we calculate the gridsize (number of blocks) from array


@cuda.jit
def tf_idf_try(a,b,c):
    i = 0
    for row in a:
        j = 0
        for tf,idf in zip(row,b):
            c[i][j] = tf * idf
            print(c[i][j])
            j += 1
        i += 1


d_A_t = cuda.to_device(A_t)
d_B_t = cuda.to_device(B_t)
d_c = cuda.to_device(c)
```

`tf_idf_try[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](d_A_t,d_B_t,d_c)`
This step takes less then 2 seconds, but this:
`c = d_c.copy_to_host()`
does not end after 15 minutes.

I'm launching code on Google Colab with GPU runtime.
Can you help me to understand where is my problem?
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IbjSLGWnK2E-c5IGpKmCVeezPYNueeQa?usp=sharing

I already trying to send c, not to d_c to my function, it doesn't help me.

Also i trying install this:

```
!apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
!pip3 install numba

import os
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = "/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice"
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvvm.so"
```

Comment: It is the kernel which takes 15 minutes, not the copy. And the reason it takes 15 minutes is because your kernel is completely serial.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @talonmies
Now i'm using @vectorize(target = cuda), it help me to fast executing my code.

```
from numba import vectorize
@vectorize(['float32(float32, float32)'], target='cuda')
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def tf_idf_try(a,b,c):
    i = 0
    for tf,idf in zip(a,b):
        c[i] = multiply(tf,idf)
        i += 1
```